# I am in Spain for 3 months and my stamp will expire one day before I return, would I have any problems?

Tags: visas, spain

I am in Spain on vacation for 3 months and my visa stamp will have expired by one day when I return to USA. Will I have any problems getting out of Spain or to enter USA?

Comment: Schengen entry stamps do not have explicit expiry dates, and it is difficult to understand what you mean by "expired one day I return" (which does not seem to be standard English). Can you please state the exact dates when you entered and left (or will leave) the Schengen area?

Comment: Also, since you say "return to USA", are you a US citizen?

Comment: OP, I guessed as to your problem and edited the title and description. PLEASE revert/undo or re-edit if I was wrong about your problem.

Comment: Did you just ask it as this [new question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92575/will-an-expired-visa-be-a-problem-on-departure)?