# Will an expired visa be a problem on departure?

Tags: visas, us-citizens, spain, overstaying

I am a US citizen and I came to Spain for 90 days’ vacation but it will be the 91st day when I arrive at the airport to leave the country. Will I have any issues getting out of Spain or entering USA?

I don’t know what type of visa I have. When I bought the tickets, there were 91 days between arrival and departure.

Comment: @SheikPaul I wouldn't call this a duplicate because enforcement is not harmonized and depends on national law. The penalty for leaving Spain a day late is therefore probably different from that for leaving Germany a day late.

Comment: You can get around this problem by leaving the Schengen area for at least one full calendar day, assuming you've counted correctly (people often don't).  For example, a weekend in Morocco or the UK would do the trick.  In any case, you'll have no trouble entering the US.

Comment: @phoog I think the immigration law is the law regardless of enforcement variances. It is better to go by the law than hoping for some consideration from some random immigration officer you might meet.

Comment: @SheikPaul But the law itself varies from one country to another, not because of the variability among immigration officers, but because of the variability of national laws.  The [Schengen Borders Code](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:02016R0399-20161006) only says that travelers can be checked on exit to verify that they have not overstayed.  It says nothing about what should happen to people who have been found to have overstayed.  The penalties imposed by the Bundestag are almost certainly different from those imposed by the Cortes Generales.

Comment: You could have edited your earlier question. You now have created multiple accounts; you can learn about merging them at http://travel.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts. (Thanks to @phoog for wording)

Comment: Regardless of which country has jurisdiction over a breach, overstaying is to be avoided. It can come back in later life as an inconvenience or embarrassment. @phoog gave a worthwhile strategy, that of channel hopping, or outright change your flight. In any event, the US authorities don't care; it's what goes on file in the European databases that should be of immediate concern.